# can you set width to make it adapt with the conten

Tags: css, tags, margin

I'm trying to do this on image below with the following CSS.

[image]

```
background: #0f0f0f none repeat scroll 0% 0%;
text-align: center;
color: #ffffdf;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 3px 9px;
height: 15px;
width: 164px;
```

My problem is, the width is fixed. How can I make it adapt to its content? also the second bar uses position: relative and manual bottom and left properties. How can I make it have at least 4 px or margin to the bar next to it?

[image]

So even though it's a different text, the padding is still the same and the margin beside the other bar is the same. I just can't figure out which CSS elements to use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hey paulie. i did include a code.

Comment: Can we **reproduce** the issue with *just* that code? If not...then it's not **complete**...is it?